# Exception during while importing data by using sqoop

Tags: hadoop

I am importing data from mysql to hive using command
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb --username root --table mytable --hive-import

and i am getting this error message:

ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/opt/sqoop/lib/jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar

I am using hadoop 2.6.0 and jdk1.7.0_79.

Please provide me a solution what i have to do to overcome this problem as i have been stuck at this point.

All the steps until importing the data has done successfully.

Comment: Does that jar file exist on HDFS?  `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:54310/opt/sqoop/lib/jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar`

Comment: NO this file does not exist.how to add this file and in which directory?